# Canvas drawImage causes ios to crash, works on web

Tags: trigger.io

When I try to do a ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 600); it crashes the ios app (emulator - forge run ios) without any useful log output.

I'm having the same issue when trying to use canvas libraries like Raphael and more specifically http://seuratjs.com/ which is what I want and now trying to do "manually".

Any ideas? Works fine on web...

Comment: Trigger Toolkit 3.3.11, iPhone Simulator 5.1 (9B176)

Comment: Yep: replicated here - we have a fix for this but are holding off until iOS 6 is released because it touches on some areas which are in flux in the betas we've seen so far. Will be fixed shortly after that launches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in v1.4.14 of the Forge platform: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-14